# Latex Breqn дублирование знаков математических операций при переносе выключных формул

Tags: latex

коллеги.

Хотел бы обсудить возможность доработки пакета breqn с целью добавления варианта переноса выключных формул с дублированием знаков математических операций, на которых происходит перенос (желательно, чтобы еще знак умножения заменялся на крестообразный).

В самом пакете такой возможности, по всей видимости, не предусмотрено (в документации такая функциональность не указана).

Из полезных источников смог найти только следующие:

1. Пакет rumathbr.sty Дениса Рябова для переноса внутритекстовых формул

   https://d-ryabov.livejournal.com/723.html?view=5843#t5843
2. Статья Михаила Гринчука, где затрагивается данная тема

   http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb17-4/tb53grin.pdf

На данный момент мне не очень ясно, возможно ли применить тот же подход, что и в пакете rumathbr.sty Дениса Рябова, в пакете breqn или требуется другое решение.

Также отмечу, что использование пакета breqn не принципиально, подойдет любой способ, который позволит автоматически переносить простые алгебраическое формулы (инженерные расчеты) с учетом дублирования знаков.

Благодарю за внимание.

Comment: Возможно есть смысл доработать пакет http://ctan.altspu.ru/macros/latex/contrib/autobreak/autobreak.pdf. Но, на самом деле, нет стандарта требующего переноса знака.

Comment: Я так полагаю, что если и есть решение, то оно подойдет как для breqn так и autobreak-а. Была еще такая идея: использовать amsmath - окружение с указанием \split, при этом разбиение исходного выражения делать python-скриптом (или Lua), но я нигде не могу найти подходящих библиотек и\или примеров подобной реализации.

Comment: Вот тут есть макрос http://www.inp.nsk.su/~baldin/LaTeX/lurs.pdf который дублирует знак в месте потенциального переноса.

Comment: Добавлю еще по поводу требований стандартов:
1. Согласно п.п.4.2.16 ГОСТ 2.105-95 ЕСКД 
"Переносить формулы на следующую строку допускается только на знаках выполняемых операций, причем знак в начале следующей строки повторяют. При переносе формулы на знаке умножения применяют знак...
2. Аналогично ГОСТ 1.5-2001 (и ГОСТ Р 54521-2011 как на него ссылающийся)
Так что требование по дублированию символов при переносе при оформлении документов обязательно.